# Conventional routing not working for simple nudge controller with only Get() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I have simple asp net core web api with a nudge controller that returns true for Get request. 
The NudgeController.cs looks as follows:

```
public class NudgeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
}
```

In StartUp.cs I have the following setup:

```
private static void ConfigureRoutes(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "nudgeRoute",
                    template: "api/{controller}"));                 
}
```

ConfigureRoutes is called in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` method in StartUp.cs

When running locally and when I navigate to http://localhost:56103/api/Nudge
I get 404 error ?
what is missing here ? and 
Are there any difference between WebApi and Asp.net core when setting up conventional routing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route template specifies no action. You're assuming `Get` should just magically be called, but ASP.NET Core has no way of knowing this and doesn't make assumptions like that. The following should fix it. It make `Get` the default action if no action segment is provided in the route.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "nudgeRoute",
        template: "api/{controller}/{action=Get}"));
```

Comment: Thanks,  follow up question, if i am not wrong, when using web api , I did not have to specify the action when using conventional routing,  and the corresponding action was was inferred from the http method, is there something changed in asp net core ?

Comment: Technically, I suppose. In ASP.NET, MVC and Web Api were separate frameworks that looked and functioned similarly, but were still different, with different rules. In Core, it's all the same. MVC vs. API is just semantics describing the *purpose* of the controller, not the type.

Comment: Thanks, but does this mean that if I add a IActionResult Post() do i have to create another  named  route  for that action ?

Comment: Yes and no. The route template I gave you will accept any action name; it just defaults to Get. However, that does mean you would specifically need to call `/api/nudge/post`. Frankly, attribute routing just works better here. You can decorate one with `[HttpGet(””)]` and the other with `[HttpPost("")]`, and you're done.